# CPython library name for python 2 and 3 using setuptools and cmake

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, python-2.x, setuptools, cpython

I'm writing python binding for a C implementation of the hdbscan algorithm. I want to build extensions for both python2 and python3. I'm using cmake and setuptools. Currently I can only properly build for one version at a time. When I try to build for both at the same time, the library name is similar for both versions depending on which one I build first in the CMakeLists.txt.

From what I understand, the python 2 library should be "PyHdbscan.so" and python 3 library should be "PyHdbscan.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so". Can somebody please help me sort this problem out. The configuration files for cmake and setuptools are shown below.

### python/CMakeLists.txt

```
set (PYTHON_MODULE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_subdirectory(python2)
add_subdirectory(python3)
```

### python/common.cmake

```
if (PYTHON)
    set(SETUP_PY_IN "${PYTHON_MODULE_DIR}/setup.py.in")
    set(SETUP_PY    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/setup.py")
    set(DEPS        "${PYTHON_MODULE_DIR}/__init__.py")
    configure_file(${SETUP_PY_IN} ${SETUP_PY})
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${OUTPUT}
                   COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} build
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${OUTPUT}
                   DEPENDS ${DEPS})

    add_custom_target(${TARGET_NAME} ALL DEPENDS ${OUTPUT})

    install(CODE "execute_process(COMMAND ${PYTHON} ${SETUP_PY} install)")
endif()
```

### python/python2/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_program(PYTHON "python2")
SET(TARGET_NAME "python2")
set(OUTPUT      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build/py3_timestamp")
include(../common.cmake)
unset(OUTPUT)
unset(TARGET_NAME)
```

### python/python2/CMakeLists.txt

```
find_program(PYTHON "python2")
SET(TARGET_NAME "python2")
set(OUTPUT      "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/build/py3_timestamp")
include(../common.cmake)
unset(OUTPUT)
unset(TARGET_NAME)
```